# Elastic Search 7.17 fails with fixed periods (search_phase_execution_exception all shards failed)

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a cluster with three nodes. The size is 3.4G and number of docs is 23478158. The index is dynamically updated and `docs.deleted` is 2957425.

We are using the Java-client and we are also running a Java-application which provides the endpoints/service to clients.

One of the endpoints is utilised by a consumer which runs verification requests to compare own data against us (the master repository). The requests are being run continually and the parameters to ES varies from 3 to approx 10. The `withSize()`-parameter in the DSL is set to 5.

The query contains a nested query with `ignoreUnampped(true)`. No sort-fields.

Every ten minutes, we get the exception in the title. The exception originates in RestClientTransport:310.

```
 310: try (JsonParser parser = mapper.jsonProvider().createParser(content)) {
                        ErrorT error = errorDeserializer.deserialize(parser, mapper);
                        // TODO: have the endpoint provide the exception constructor
                        throw new ElasticsearchException(endpoint.id(), (ErrorResponse) error);
                    }
```

> co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed
> at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:313)
> at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:153)
> at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1754)

I have logged the parameters which are sent to the query causing the error for reproduction, but have failed to reproduce. I.e. these parameters in the query are yielding a valid response. It just doesn't seem to be deterministic.

It is a massive amount of requests against the application, so my hunch is that some cache is filling up.

Thoughts?

Comment: Any more stacktrace ?

Comment: @Mathew most were from the proprietary code itself, except from the lines containing the RestHighlevelClient. I'll post this on Monday, when I have access to the company system.

Comment: @mathew here it is

co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed
 at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:313)
 at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:153)
 at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1754)
 at ske.folkeregister.elasticsearch.index.AbstractReadAlias.search(AbstractReadAlias.java:27)

Comment: @Mathew I also have a hunch that the GC is running every 10 minutes, this making the app non-responsive. I'll set up an agent to monitor the memory of the application-pod for starters.

Comment: @Mathew here is the de-brief: the node was running on a server with 4 CPUs. One search request takes up 1 CPU. When the GC was running, it took almost all the resources, therefore noting left for the queries. That's what the operator said.